# Hide Appendix while being able to refer contents

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, appendices

I want to hide (don't want in the final PDF) an Appendix containing some theorems and Algorithms which I need to refer in the paper. It helps me to keep the reference number same as the extended version of my paper which is in the bibliography. Is there any automated way to do that in LaTeX by hiding some Appendix or by other means?

Comment: may be with `\includeonly{...}` command.

Comment: I actually used a hack as I was in a hurry. I compiled the whole file keeping the appendix and later split the pdf leaving the appendix out. I guess a really blunt way to do it, nonetheless it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are presumably using `\ref` to refer to the numbers in the appendix,
so you will have to save them after the "extended version" of your paper
is final.

these references will be in the `.aux` file on lines beginning `\newlabel`.
copy them into a new file, call it perhaps `thm-labels.tex` and then
`\input{thm-labels}` in the preamble of your "compact version" of the
paper.  just before `\begin{document}` is probably a good location.

this approach assumes that there will be separate "main" files for the
"extended" and "compact" versions of the paper; the text of the body and
the appendix are best kept in separate files, since they will not change.
the reason for suggesting this approach is that if the appendix precedes
the bibliography (for example), the page numbers will be different in the
"compact version", and getting everything that goes along with that will
require processing the files more than once, wiping out any previous
versions of the `.aux` file that contain the desired label/reference
information.

do make sure that you get the labels from the *final* version, and if you
make any later changes, be sure to refresh the `thm-labels` file.